# How can I stop EF Core from creating a filtered index on a nullable column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have this model:

```
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int LevelId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LevelId")]
    public Level Level { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
    public DateTime? DeletedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And index configured via Fluent API:

```
entityBuilder.HasIndex(e => new { e.LevelId, e.Name, e.DeletedAt })
    .IsUnique();
```

It's creating a table with a unique filtered index. How can I prevent EF from adding the filter? I just want the index and don't want it filtered.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Creating filtered index excluding `NULL` values is the default EF Core behavior for *unique* indexes containing nullable columns.

You can use [HasFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalindexbuilderextensions.hasfilter?view=efcore-2.0) fluent API to change the filter condition or turn it off by passing `null` as `sql` argument:

```
entityBuilder.HasIndex(e => new { e.LevelId, e.Name, e.DeletedAt })
    .IsUnique()
    .HasFilter(null);
```

Comment: Note that `.HasFilter(null)` must appear AFTER `.IsUnique()`, otherwise filter is still generated.

Comment: Why is creating filtered index excluding NULL values the default behavior in EF Core? Any good reason for having that as the default?

Comment: Otherwise you can have only one NULL value in that field for all the rows. Usually you'd want the value to be unique for those records where a value has been entered, while still maintaining the possibility of multiple NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add more explanation to @Ivan Stoev answer, just for us to have in mind:

```
entityBuilder.HasIndex(e => new { e.Prop1, e.Prop2, e.Prop3 })
.IsUnique()
.HasFilter(null);
```

but why EF Core adds automatically NOT NULL filter is because in SQL

```
NULL != NULL
```

like in C# null == null. This is one of articles about this topic:

https://modern-sql.com/feature/is-distinct-from

Comment: You (may need more reputation but) should add your explanation as a comment on the referenced answer or add the explanation into the other answer by editing it. No need to provide a slightly more generalised version of an existing answer.