# SQL Server - EF Core - Custom Constraint where all flags against id must be false except for one

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have a table generated through ef core code first and need to assign a constraint where all the flags in records with a specific primary key id must be false except for one which has to be true, so it will always have a single record that has the flag set to true.

for example in the picture below, I expect only one item to have isAccountHolder to be true and if there is only one record in the table then that must have isAccountHolder set to true.

I am wondering if this can be done using the code first approach. I have tried the following but it does not seem to work.

```
    builder
        .HasIndex(p => new {p.AccountHolderCustomerId, p.IsAccountHolder})
        .HasFilter("[IsAccountHolder] = 1");
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to express that in EF but In SQL Server you will have a unique filtered index on AccountHolderCustomerId and IsAccountHolder where IsAccountHolder = 1. Also, please note that AccountHolderCustomerId is not and can not be the primary key of this table - since a primary key is unique by definition.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here:
[How can I stop EF Core from creating a filtered index on a nullable column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48030014/how-can-i-stop-ef-core-from-creating-a-filtered-index-on-a-nullable-column?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
        builder
            .HasIndex(p => new {p.AccountHolderCustomerId, p.IsAccountHolder})
            .IsUnique()
            .HasFilter("[IsAccountHolder] = 1");
```